# SQL select only rows which have same column value

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

I need some hints.. I got a table which looks like that:

```
id  fruit   delicious
1   apple   1
2   apple   0
3   apple   1
4   cherry  1
5   cherry  1
6   cherry  1
7   banana  0
8   banana  0
9   banana  0
```

For this table I want to create a statement which will only return the fruits which are 
completely delicious but not the fruits which are partially delicious. 
In this example only "cherry" should be returned.

Currently I just got this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE delicious <> 0
```

but this would also return apple and banana.

I'm a bit clueless how I could archive that and looking forward to some hints.

**EDIT: Thank you very much for your replys. Unfortunately the flag "delicious" is a char and not an integer**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by the `fruit` and take only those having zero records with `delicious = 0`

```
SELECT fruit 
FROM fruits 
GROUP BY fruit
HAVING sum(case when delicious = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: Nice inversion of logic, although must admit had to read it twice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I casted delicious to int and it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Just look for those that have a min delicious value of 1

```
SELECT Id, Fruit FROM fruits
GROUP BY Id, Fruit
HAVING min(delicious) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way, but can use in many situations.

```
SELECT DISTINCT fruit 
FROM fruits 
WHERE NOT fruit IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT fruit 
  FROM fruits 
  WHERE delicious = 0
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works

```
SELECT fruit, sum(delicious) AS TotalScore, count(fruit) AS TotalFruits
FROM ForgeRock
GROUP BY fruit
HAVING TotalScore = TotalFruits
```